# How to loop through this Python dict and search if value is there

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a Python dict like this:

```
{
    'TagList': [
        {
            'Key': 'tag1',
            'Value': 'val'
        },
        {
            'Key': 'tag2',
            'Value': 'val'
        },
        {
            'Key': 'tag3',
            'Value': 'val'
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

How do I loop through this dict to search if the `Key` `tag1` is available.

EDIT: @Willem Van Onsem's solution works great. But I forgot to mention that I need to check more than 1 Key, so for example:

```
If Tag1 and Tag2 exist => true
If either Tag1 or Tag2 is missing` => false
```

Comment: do you have more keys than `'TagList'` in your dict?

Comment: No only 1 key like TagList

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your dictionary contains a key `'TagList'` and you are only interested in the dictionaries in the list associated with that key, you can use:

```
any(subd.get('Key') == 'tag1' for subd in the_dict['TagList'])
```

Where the dictionary `the_dict` is the one you want to inspect.

We thus use the `any(..)` builtin with a generator expression that iterates through the list associated with the `'TagList'` key. For each such subdictionary, we check if the key `'Key'` is associated with the value `'tag1'`. In case no key `'Key'` is present in one or more of the subdictionaries, that is not a problem since we use `.get(..)`.

For your given dictionary, this generates:

```
>>> any(subd.get('Key') == 'tag1' for subd in the_dict['TagList'])
True
```

## Multiple values

If you want to check that **all values** of a list occur in the subdictionaries, we can use the following two-liner (given the "tag names" are hashable, strings are hashable):

```
tag_names = {subd.get('Key') for subd in the_dict['TagList']}
all(tag in tag_names for tag in ('tag1','tag2'))
```

Here the `all(..)` will return `True` if *all* the tag names in the tuple at the right (`('tag1','tag2')`) are each in at least one subdictionary.

For example:

```
>>> all(tag in tag_names for tag in ('tag1','tag2'))
True
>>> all(tag in tag_names for tag in ('tag1','tag2','tag3'))
True
>>> all(tag in tag_names for tag in ('tag1','tag2','tag4'))
False
```

Comment: Thanks, this 1-line solution works great. Can I add another condition to this code to check if both tag1 "and" tag2 are there?

Comment: @Casper: that's a harder problem. But it is possible. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Wow many thanks, I never knew about these elegant functions of Python, now I can get rid of those for loops...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem hi Willem, I stumbled upon this new format and the current answer doesn't seem to apply. 

{
    'Tags': {
        'Key': 'Value'
    }
}

I want to check if the value 'Key' matches my search key

Comment: @Casper: please edit your question, or ask a new one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following loop:

```
for key in d:
    for item in d[key]:
        for deep_key in item:
            if item[deep_key] == 'tag1': # whatever you are looking for
                print('Found')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import ChainMap

'tag1' in ChainMap(*d['TagList'])
```

or if you want the tag1's value

```
ChainMap(*d['TagList'])['tag1']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your `dictionary` as `a_dict` then their is the other way to find the `Key tag1`. If found then it will `return` the `True` else `False`.

```
tag_list = a_dict['TagList']
result = next((True for item in tag_list if item["Key"] == "tag1"),False)
print(result)
```

for multiple :

```
a,b=next((True for item in tag_list if item["Key"] == "ta1"),False),\
    next((True for item in tag_list if item["Key"] == "tag2"), False)
result = a and b
print(result)
```